# Flexbox расстановка

Tags: flexbox

Возможно кто-то подскажет как это реализовать на flex[image: введите сюда описание изображения]box с тем условием, что правый блок в мобильной версии станет между меню и строкой поиска

Comment: из разряда сделайте за меня.

Comment: Предложите свое решение

Comment: У меня нет решения. Я не знаю. Вот спрашиваю, возможно, кто подскажет или натолкнет на мысль как делать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
div {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, silver, blue);
}

.right {
  float: right;
  height: 4.5em;
  width: 30%;
  margin-left: .5em;
}

.left {
  height: 2em;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.top {
  margin-bottom: .5em;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  section {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  
  .top {
    order: -1;
  }
  
  .right {
    margin: 0 auto .5em;
  }
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="right"></div>
  <div class="left top"></div>
  <div class="left"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: Здравствуйте Вы используете em есть разница с px ?

Comment: @Leks, это разные единицы измерения. В данном случае принципиальной разницы нет и можно перевести.